# Voltage function on a symmetric graph

Tags: graph-theory, harmonic-functions, random-graphs

Consider a *connected* graph $\mathrm{G},$ locally finite (every vertex has finite neighbours), satisfying the following "circular condition": there exists a vertex $o$ such that for every pair of vertices $x$ and $y$ at the same distance from $o$ there exists a *graph automorphism* sending $x$ to $y$ (a bijection between vertices and edges that respects adjacency) while leaving $o$ fixed. If one think of planar graphs, any graph with the form of a spider web, though examples may arise in many dimensions.

Suppose a $h$ is a harmonic function on the vertices of $\mathrm{G}$ except at $o,$ where its value is specified to be one. This is to say, $h(o) = 1$ and for every other vertex $x \neq o,$ we have $h(x) = \dfrac{1}{d(x)} \sum\limits_{y \sim x} h(y),$ where $d(x)$ is  the "degree" of $x,$ that is, the number of neighbours $x$ has.

> **Claim:** the function $h$ satisfies that $h(x) = h(y)$ for every pair of nodes (vertices) $x$ and $y$ at the same distance from $o.$

The circular condition implies at once $d(x) = d(z)$ for all $x$ and $z$ at the same distance from $o.$ Any ideas and hints appreciated. Also, assuming the distance from $o$ to $z$ to be $n,$ I have tried to expand $h(z) = \dfrac{I + J + K}{d(x)},$ where $I$ is the sum of $h(t)$ for $t$ a neighbour of $z$ and at distance $n - 1,$ $J$ the sum for vertices at distance $n$ and $K$ the sum for distance $n + 1$ (there can't be other type neighbours of $z$). But the problem is that the equations become really messy and I suppose there must be simpler methods than brute force.

Comment: You said $\mathbb Z^2$ is good; then the claim is not true (consider $x=(n,m)$ and $h(x) = 1+n^2-m^2$).

Comment: Come to think of it, maybe the condition is subtly different? Maybe the said automorphism sending $x$ to $y$ _should leave $o$ in place_? Then $\mathbb Z^2$ is not good, but the claim might hold.

Comment: You are very right! I was thinking in leaving $o$ fixed, like rotations. And $\mathbf{Z}^2$ is then not good.

Comment: I thought a bit more, and no, the claim will not hold even then.

Comment: I'd be really impressed to see a counterexample, because any two vertices at the same distance from $o$ are essentially the same, so $h$ ought to satisfy the same systems of equations.

Comment: You can also take as a counterexample a bi-infinite path, like $\mathbb Z$ with the special vertex at $0$. The voltages on the positive vertices may be chosen independently of the voltages on the negative vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of an infinite binary tree with $o$ being its root. Then assign the values for $h(x)$ as follows.

Left branch: $h(x)={1\over2}$ for the vertex adjacent to the root, then $1\over4$ for its children, then $1\over8$ for the next level, and so on.

Right branch: $h(x)=1$ for all $x$.

...

So no, the claim does not hold.

---

Come to think of it, why would you call it a *voltage* function? Supposedly because it represents the voltage values in an electric network shaped according to our graph, if you touch it with electrodes at certain points (those where we specify $h(x)$). But wait, there is only *one* such point ($o$), and we can't have any currents in a setup with only one wire attached, can we? Why, we can, only the other electrode(s) must be removed to infinity. Can we have many of those? Sure, why not. Can they have different voltages?

Well, that's just what I did.

Comment: Very nice! I am actually quite impressed because the author's hint of the problem is, I quote: "By symmetry, all vertices at a given distance from $o$ have the same voltage, therefore they may be identified without changin any voltages or currents..."

Comment: Maybe you are looking for other ways to patch the problem statement so as to salvage the claim? Well, here's one: request that all those imaginary "electrodes at infinity" have the same voltage - in other words, that $h(x)\to0$ as the distance from $o$ grows to $\infty$. _Then_ it might be true.

Comment: I am pretty sure this counterexample is a counterexample not only to my claim, but the book's exercise.

Comment: What is the exercise, then?

Comment: Pretty much the same but with arbitrary resistances/conductances. I assumed seeing the case all conductances equal one would shed light as to why I can't prove it.

Comment: I see. So your claim is only a particular case of it. Well, then my counterexample is indeed breaking both.